# Keep session/cookies in React after authenticating with Passport

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, cookies, passport.js

My React application is logging in successfully, and the backend is also working successfully.

Question: What is going wrong here? This works fine in Postman and retains my cookie/session information.

How do I make sure react retains the necessary authentication details for fetching from the API?

However, when rendering a new page and accessing my API to get user information, I'm received a `401 Unauthorized` error.

I am using an `emitter` to fetch my data.

**My API works fine using Postman but does not work in React**. Code below:

Passport login & User serialization:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  connection.query("select * from users where id = "+ id, function(err,user) {
      done(err, user[0]);
    });
});

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
  },
  function(req, email, password, done) {
    connection.query("select * from users where email = '"+ email +"'",function(err,user) {
         console.log(user);
       console.log("above row object");
       if (err)
          return done(err);
       if (user.length) {
          return done(null, false);
       } else {
          var passwordHash = sha1(req.body.password)
          var newUserMysql = new Object();
          newUserMysql.name     = req.body.name;
          newUserMysql.password = passwordHash;
                    newUserMysql.email    = req.body.email;
          newUserMysql.group_id = req.body.group_id;

                var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users (name, password, email, group_id) values ('"+ req.body.name +"','"+ passwordHash +"','"+ req.body.email +"','"+ req.body.group_id +"')";
                  console.log(insertQuery);

          connection.query(insertQuery,function(err,user){
            newUserMysql.id = user.insertId;

            return done(null, newUserMysql);
                });
      }
      });
  }));
```

My react emitter for profile information:

```
export default class ProfileController {
constructor(emitter) {
    this.Emitter = emitter;
}
init() {
    this.Emitter.on('GetMyUser', this.getMyUser.bind(this));
}

getMyUser() {
        fetch(`${domain}/api/user/self`, {//This is where it appears to be failing!!!
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
            this.Emitter.emit('OnGetMyUser', res.data); 
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            this.Emitter.emit('OnGetMyUser', 'Failed to load User from Controller.');
            Alert.error('Failed to load user.');
        });
}
```

}

And finally, the route itself in my API:

```
app.get('/api/user/self', function(req, res) {//Get current user by id profile information 
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.status(401).send({code: 401, message: "Unauthorized"});
    }

    connection.query("SELECT id, name, email, group_id FROM users WHERE id = ?",  [
        req.user.id
    ], function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send({code: 500, message: "Internal Server Error"});
        }
        else if (result.rowCount === 0) {
            return res.status(404).send({code: 404, message: "Not found"});
        }

        console.log(result);                
        return res.send(userFull(result));
    });
});
```